# Regd. map grid structure in GPS data mining

Tags: gps, gis, data-mining

I have been exploring the GPS data mining literature esp. for problems like anomalous trajectory detection, time travel prediction, etc and one very common method I see is dividing the data or map into grids. Can any one please explain the logic of this? Are the coordinates euclidean in this case? Is grid decomposition really necessary?
I would be grateful if someone can also give/ quote some links or materials I should explore. I am new to this field, so please pardon me if the question is very obvious.

Thanks & Regards,
Lesnar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they are not euclidean. But they don't have to be. The grids are not rectangles anymore, but can be treated as such for some operations.

If you create a lat/long grid, then each cell by means of meters is not rectangular. However it defines a zone where you add a counter, which has a clear inside/outside definition. And you can use cartesian operations (Rectangle.inside())

So the lat / lon span is constant for each cell, but not the longitudinal meters span, which shrinks by cos(latitude).

If one needs a grid with equal grid cells sizes by means of meters, then one 
has to transform the geo coordinates before.

Comment: Thanks Alex! Just one more doubt.... what tools we should look at? I have been doing most of my work in R and hence would prefer it. Any idea if there`s any package or method for this in R?

Comment: A regular grid, you best implement yourself, as an 2d-array: similar to this:  xpos = longitude / cellSizeDegrees; ypos = latitude / celSizeDegrees; grid[xpos][ypos].addInfo(...)

Comment: Ok got it! Thanks again!